# Is there a way to allow a two way functions with text area?

Tags: javascript, html

I made this custom language replacer. But it works both ways. But the problem happens when you first do a translation from first text area. It outputs it inside the textarea beside it. But when I then go and delete the text inside the output. it will not let me use that textarea to get a reverse back to the custom language. it will only allow this if I refresh the page. Which I would like to evoid having to do.

```js
function TranslatetoUnseen() {
  var Translation = document.getElementById("Unseen").value;

  Translation = Translation.replace(/ㅏ/g, "A"); // if ㅏ then A
  Translation = Translation.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '); // when to many spaces
  Translation = Translation.toLowerCase();

  document.getElementById("English").innerHTML = Translation[0].toUpperCase() + Translation.slice(1);
}


function TranslatetoEnglish() {
  var TranslationEng = document.getElementById("English").value;

  TranslationEng = TranslationEng.replace(/A/g, "ㅏ"); // if A then ㅏ
  TranslationEng = TranslationEng.replace(/a/g, "ㅏ"); // if a then ㅏ
  TranslationEng = TranslationEng.replace(/\s\s+/g, '  '); // Adds 1 more space

  document.getElementById("Unseen").innerHTML = TranslationEng;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" class="center" width="50%">
  <tr style="font-size: 150%;">
    <th width="386">Unseen</th>
    <th width="386">English</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><textarea id="Unseen" oninput=TranslatetoUnseen() size="4" wrap="hard" draggable="false"></textarea></td>
    <td><textarea id="English" oninput=TranslatetoEnglish() size="4" wrap="hard" draggable="false"></textarea></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I input something inside a box and then want to do it the reverse, it doesn't allow it. When it should allow it to go both ways

Comment: your description is not very clear. Could you make a runnable snippet so that we can see the problem?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I just ran your code and it does work both ways. Can you clarify what do you mean by "it doesnt allow it"?

Comment: When I do a long string of symbols that it should translate. It wil do it. But when I then delete all the text in the English textarea and try to type english. It will type the english but wont translate it to "Unseen"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If there is no character at 0 (empty string) you get an error in this statement: `Translation[0].toUpperCase()`
- use `.value` instead of `innerHTML`

```js
function TranslatetoUnseen() {
  var Translation = document.getElementById("Unseen").value;
  Translation = Translation.replace(/ㅏ/g, "A"); // if ㅏ then A
  Translation = Translation.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '); // when to many spaces
  Translation = Translation.toLowerCase();
  document.getElementById("English").value = Translation.length === 0? "" : Translation[0].toUpperCase() + Translation.slice(1);
}


function TranslatetoEnglish() {
  var TranslationEng = document.getElementById("English").value;
  TranslationEng = TranslationEng.replace(/A/g, "ㅏ"); // if A then ㅏ
  TranslationEng = TranslationEng.replace(/a/g, "ㅏ"); // if a then ㅏ
  TranslationEng = TranslationEng.replace(/\s\s+/g, '  '); // Adds 1 more space
  document.getElementById("Unseen").value = TranslationEng;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" class="center" width="50%">
  <tr style="font-size: 150%;">
    <th width="386">Unseen</th>
    <th width="386">English</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><textarea id="Unseen" oninput=TranslatetoUnseen() size="4" wrap="hard" draggable="false"></textarea></td>
    <td><textarea id="English" oninput=TranslatetoEnglish() size="4" wrap="hard" draggable="false"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried everything and this seems to have fixed it